# make git diff ignore time stamp in two files

Tags: git, github

I have two log files that I want to compare the differences, the problem is that they have lines with time stamp that I don't want to recognize as difference, for example, running a `git diff file1.txt file2.txt` and git will output:

```
--- a/training_dir/solo_r50_diceloss_1xsizemaskloss/log.txt
+++ b/training_dir/solo_r50_diceloss_1xsizemaskloss_coordconv_adptivepooltoclsgridsize/log.txt
@@ -1,29 +1,30 @@
-2020-01-13 09:35:49,070 fcos_core INFO: Using 4 GPUs
-2020-01-13 09:35:49,070 fcos_core INFO: Namespace(config_file='configs/solo/embed_mask_R50_1x.yaml', distributed=True, local_rank=0, opts=['DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS', '2', 'OUTPUT_DIR', 'training_dir/solo_r50_diceloss_1xsizemaskloss'], skip_test=False)
-2020-01-13 09:35:49,070 fcos_core INFO: Collecting env info (might take some time)
-2020-01-13 09:35:52,675 fcos_core INFO: 
+2020-01-28 15:54:12,337 fcos_core INFO: Using 4 GPUs
+2020-01-28 15:54:12,337 fcos_core INFO: Namespace(config_file='configs/solo/embed_mask_R50_1x.yaml', distributed=True, local_rank=0, opts=['DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS', '2', 'OUTPUT_DIR', 'training_dir/solo_r50_diceloss_1xsizemaskloss_coordconv_adptivepooltoclsgridsize'], skip_test=False)
+2020-01-28 15:54:12,338 fcos_core INFO: Collecting env info (might take some time)
+2020-01-28 15:54:16,685 fcos_core INFO:
```

but actually those lines are the same except they have different time stampes in the begining, so how can make git ignore those tima stampes.

I find git diff has an option of `--word-diff-regex=<regex>`, but don't know to use it, can anyone help ?

Comment: Does the diff filter I mentioned below work?

Answer (score 1):

That is what [`git diff` textconv](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files) is for.

So:

```
cd /path/to/repo
bash
git config diff.noTimestamp.textconv "sed -E 's/^\S+ \S+ //g'"

# create a .gitattributes file
*.txt diff=noTimestamp
```

Put the `.gitattributes` file in the parent folder of all the `*.txt` files with timestamps.

Then try:

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=. @~
# or
git diff --word-diff @~
```

Comment: Thank you, so I should do `git config --global filter.noTimestamp.smudge 'sed "s/^\S+ \S+ //g"'` and then it will generate a `.gitattributes file` file, then I put the file in the same folder with *.txt files, and then I can do `git diff ` and it will ignore the time stamps?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: but running `git config --global filter.noTimestamp.smudge 'sed "s/^\S+ \S+ //g"'` does not generate a `.gitattributes` file

Comment: No those are two separate operations. One is a command to type, the other is a file to create manually.

Comment: I tried it, not work, should I modify this `sed "s/^\S+ \S+ //g"`, could you please give a short example demonstrating it works?

Comment: @K.Wanter Sure: on the regex side: https://regex101.com/r/i2RhpR/1

Comment: @K.Wanter I have rewritten the answer: you needed a diff filter, not a content filter. I tested it: it does work.

Comment: Also, the `.git/info/attributes` file is repo-local, handy for local-use attributes like this where you don't necessarily want to impose the classifications on others.

Comment: I think the attribute line s/b `diff=noTimestamp`, not `filter=`etc., no?

Comment: @jthill Yes. Fixed.